# Dial: Invalid callerId value

Tags: twilio

I have an intercom system I am trying to setup SIP within, to call a remote office instead of a local handset in the building.

I've setup a SIP domain in Twilio and connected the intercom with the credentials. However when I get the intercom to call when the button is pressed Twilio errors with the invalid caller id.

`callerId="sip:tslg@tslg.sip.twilio.com:5060"`

The above is what appears in the body of the message when I inspect the error in Twilio.

The intercom has no way of setting a caller id. Is there any way I can set this in Twilio to always have a caller id?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the callerId in the Dial TwiML. When making a call across the PSTN, it has to be set to either a Twilio number in your account or a verified CallerID.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#callerid